# Estimote beacons - Difference between monitoring and ranging listeners

Tags: android, estimote

I don't seem to really understand the difference between the MonitoringListener and the RangingListener.

In my particular use case I would like to constantly know all beacons within range, and would like to know when a region associated with any of them is exited.

This is a snippet of what I'm talking about:

```
    beaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, final List<Beacon> beacons) {

        }
    });
    beaconManager.setMonitoringListener(new BeaconManager.MonitoringListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEnteredRegion(Region region, List<Beacon> beacons) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onExitedRegion(Region region) {

        }
    });
```

I don't really get the difference between the onBeaconsDiscovered and onEnteredRegion methods. When you start listening for any one of them you pass a Region as a parameter, so that confuses me a little bit more, since at first glance I assumed the first one was just constantly searching while the other one just looked for a specific Region.

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The difference is not really in the callbacks themselves, but rather in how and when they get called.

`MonitoringListener.onEnteredRegion` and `MonitoringListener.onExitedRegion` are triggered whenever you cross the boundary of the region passed to `BeaconManager.startMonitoring`. Once you enter the region and `onEnteredRegion` gets called, you won't get another notification unless you exit and then re-enter the region.

On the contrary, `RangingListener.onBeaconsDiscovered` is being triggered continuously (by default: every 1 second) and gets you a list of beacons discovered by your Android device - as long as they match the region passed to `BeaconManager.startRanging`.

#### Example:

Imagine you have a beacon with UUID = X, major = Y and minor = Z. You define your region as follows:

```
Region region = new Region("myRegion", X, Y, Z)
```

And then start both ranging and monitoring:

```
beaconManager.startRanging(region);
beaconMangeer.startMonitoring(region);
```

The timeline of callbacks invocations may look like this:

```ruby
# assuming you start outside the range of the beacon
 1s: onBeaconsDiscovered(<myRegion>, <empty list of beacons>)
 2s: onBeaconsDiscovered(<myRegion>, <empty list of beacons>)
 3s: onBeaconsDiscovered(<myRegion>, <empty list of beacons>)
# now you move closer to the beacon, ending up in its range
 4s: *onEnteredRegion*(<myRegion>, <a list with the "X/Y/Z" beacon>)
   + onBeaconsDiscovered(<myRegion>, <a list with the "X/Y/Z" beacon>)
 5s: onBeaconsDiscovered(<myRegion>, <a list with the "X/Y/Z" beacon>)
 6s: onBeaconsDiscovered(<myRegion>, <a list with the "X/Y/Z" beacon>)
 7s: onBeaconsDiscovered(<myRegion>, <a list with the "X/Y/Z" beacon>)
# now you move out of the beacon's range again
 8s: *onExitedRegion*(<myRegion>)
   + onBeaconsDiscovered(<myRegion>, <empty list of beacons>)
 9s: onBeaconsDiscovered(<myRegion>, <empty list of beacons>)
10s: onBeaconsDiscovered(<myRegion>, <empty list of beacons>)
```

*Note that in reality, Bluetooth scanning might not be as responsive as in the example above.*